# CORBA + Tomcat 6 + Webapp classloader leak

Tags: java, tomcat, corba

**EDIT**:

I found classloader leak in my webapplication.
It boils down to 3rd party library initializing CORBA via JNDI's COS naming service and not exposing a call to cleanly shutdown JNDI's context. This leaves some CORBA related threads and other resources referencing my webapp classloader and preventing it from being garbage collected. This results in OutOfMemory Error: PermGen after few redeploys/reloads.

For now I increased the PermGen memory in JVM and it makes the intervals between server crashes longer. This obviously is not a fix but a workaround (and a poor one for that matter).

**I guess my question is is there any way I can cleanly shutdown JNDI context without holding reference to it**. My instincts tell me no, but maybe I don't know about some magic feature of JNDI that would allow me to get hold of that context.

So the way the 3rd party library initializes CORBA objects is something along this lines (exception handling and other details omited for brevity):

```
private CorbaObjectAggregate initCorba() {
    InitialContext ctx = null;
    CorbaObjectAggregate corbaObjects = new CorbaObjectAggregate();
    ORB orb = null;
    Properties env = getContextEnvironment();
    String[] args = null;
    orb = ORB.init(args, null);
    env.put("java.naming.corba.orb", orb);
    ctx = new InitialContext(env);
    //a bunch of object lookups follow
    corbaObjects.someCorbaObjectReference = (SomeCorbaObjectClass) ctx.lookup("somePaht");
    return corbaObjects;
}
```

So the reference to `ctx` is gone after that method finishes executing...

I tried stopping the threads manually but it didn't fix the leak. I guess there are some other corba resources holding onto classloader. I suppose I could try to hunt them down in some cleanup method and free the classloader this way, but I was hoping for some cleaner solution.

Just for clarity, the 3rd party library is closed source and I can't really change it. It's also not viable option to get support form the company behind it.

Comment: *(this is not an answer, hence the comment)*...  Personally I'd ask the developer of the 3rd party API to fix their mess.  Meanwhile you *could* mitigate the issue by either using a bigger PermGen or by using a JVM that would **not** be an Oracle/Sun one, because PermGen, IIRC, is an Oracle/Sun specificity.  *(that said oh the memories: I remember discovering by myself some terrible Tomcat + Sun JVM + Hibernate permgen issue back in the days when hardly any info could be found on the subject ; )*  Back then we "fixed" our problem by switching to Resin IIRC (really many years ago).

Comment: Unfortunately the 3rd party developers don't exist :). This is a legacy system that our application needs to integrate with. But that aside, I am not sure the problem is in the library directly. Like I mentioned, the thread is actually created by the CORBA subsystem, so I imagine any library using CORBA would trigger that thread to be created. That said I am by no means CORBa expert. Unfortunately changing app server is no-go either.

Comment: as a crappy workaround, which may save you time, you may pass the Oracle/SUn JVM the argument that create a bigger PermGen... Something like this: -XX:MaxPermSize=512m   It's of course just a temporary workaround.  What about Tomcat 6's *"Find Leaks"* option (you can call it for example in the Tomcat manager webapp), does it find the same leak too?

Comment: Yip, We've applied the crappy workaround already. This extends intervals between crashes... better than nothing though not ideal. As for the "Find Leaks" thingy, it just tells you which application leak and not what causes the leak nevermind how to fix it :). It detects the leaking application though.

Comment: On a JEE appserver the ORB.init call can cause problems. According to the corba specs ORB.init(args, null) will create a new ORB instance. When an ORB instance is created it will create 5 threads (4 ListenerThreads and 1 ReaderThread). These threads will only be destroyed when the ORB instance is destroyed. We had this problem with an ORB.init call in a 3rd party library. Ran out of native memory after 300+ ORBs and 1500+ threads were created. Tests showed that changing the ORB.init call to a jndi (java:comp/ORB) lookup was the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is going to be tricky to fix. There are likely to be two issues:
- classes loaded from the JAR holding a reference to the web-app class loader
- threads started by that process having the web-app class loader as their context class-loader.

Something along the following lines should help:

1. Move the JAR to $CATALINA_BASE/lib. That will mean that the classes are loaded by the common class loader. The down side is that they are also visible to and shared by every web application.
2. Find out where in your application the initialisation is triggered. Before that code executes, set the thread context class loader to the system class loader (or the parent of the current (web-app) class loader) and reset the thread context class loader after the init call. That should mean any threads created do not have the web-app class loader as the context class loader.

If threads get created at other points in time, fixing this could get very tricky, very quickly.

For some background that may help understand what is going on, see:
http://people.apache.org/~markt/presentations/2010-11-04-Memory-Leaks-60mins.pdf

To see the sort of thing Tomcat does internally to work-around these issues see:
http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tomcat/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/core/JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener.java?view=annotate

Comment: +1 for a very informative response. Yes, I was considering moving the jar to container level, but, unlikely as it seems, I managed to get through to the people behind the code and after many email after they acknowledged the bug in their code, so hopefully this will be fixed where it should be. Your PDF is a great read and reinforces what I figured out from various sources when investigating the issue. The second option you gave is interesting, though it looks like last resort really, ie. dirty hack ;)

Comment: I just though I may as well flag it as an accepted answer. It's scary how many libraries can cause the issue and it's interesting to learn what kind of measures are taken on container level to safe guard against them. Thanks a lot for your response.